EAS (Expo Build) Error: Gradle build failed with unknown error [SOLVED]
I can't build my Expo project. I tried to fix my dependencies but I got this error again. I don't understand where I am mistaken.
See my debug log (PNG)
My dependencies:
   "dependencies": {
        "@expo/vector-icons": "^14.0.2",
        "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "1.23.1",
        "@react-native-firebase/analytics": "^20.1.0",
        "@react-native-firebase/app": "^20.1.0",
        "@react-native-firebase/auth": "^20.1.0",
        "@react-native-firebase/firestore": "^20.1.0",
        "@react-native-firebase/storage": "^20.1.0",
        "@react-native-google-signin/google-signin": "^12.2.1",
        "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.7.0",
        "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.2",
        "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^2.2.6",
        "@tanstack/react-query": "^5.51.1",
        "expo": "~51.0.24",
        "expo-dev-client": "~4.0.21",
        "expo-font": "~12.0.7",
        "expo-image": "~1.12.13",
        "expo-linear-gradient": "~13.0.2",
        "expo-linking": "~6.3.1",
        "expo-router": "~3.5.20",
        "expo-splash-screen": "~0.27.5",
        "expo-status-bar": "~1.12.1",
        "expo-system-ui": "~3.0.7",
        "expo-web-browser": "~13.0.3",
        "react": "18.2.0",
        "react-dom": "18.2.0",
        "react-native": "^0.74.4",
        "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.16.1",
        "react-native-reanimated": "~3.10.1",
        "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.10.5",
        "react-native-screens": "3.31.1",
        "react-native-web": "~0.19.10",
        "react-query": "^3.39.3",
        "react-redux": "^9.1.2"
      },

My babel.config.js file:
module.exports = function (api) {
  api.cache(true)
  return {
    presets: ["babel-preset-expo"],
    plugins: ["react-native-reanimated/plugin"],
  }
}


Thanks, in advance.
I'm trying to build my expo project but, I get an EAS build error.
EDIT:  The issue was about app name in the app.json file. Changing "İ" to "I" solved my problem.

Please never post log on other plaintext output as screenshot.

It is a screenshot from expo.dev log. I cropped it to make more readable.

The issue was about app name in the app.json file.  Changing "İ" to "I" solved my problem.
